# What is difference between res.append(val) and res[:]+[value]?

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

```
def dfs(node, target: int, path: List[int]):
        if isLeaf(node):
            if target - node.val == 0:
                result.append(path[:] + [node.val])
            return
        if target < 0:
            return
        
        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left, target - node.val, path[:] + [node.val])
        if node.right:
            dfs(node.right, target - node.val, path[:] + [node.val])
```

In the above method, if I use "path[:] + [node.val]" I will get a list of list in the result ([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]). But instead of "path[:] + [node.val]" this if i  use "path.append(node.val)" i get empty list of list ([[], []]). So if we use recursion, should we pass the new copy of the newly constructed list?

Comment: Side-note: `res[:]+[value]` is exactly equivalent to `res + [value]`, except it pointlessly makes a copy of the (presumably possibly large) `res`. `+` is already going to perform a shallow copy, so using `[:]` to explicitly shallow copy as well is just wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

`path[:] + [x]` is the same as `[*path, x]` which makes a copy of the `path` list with `x` inserted at the end.

`result.append(x)` will mutate (modify) the existing `result` and insert `x` at the end of the list.

> So if we use recursion, should we pass the new copy of the newly constructed list?

Yes. Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like variable reassignment, single-branch (`if`) conditionals, and other side effects.

Here's what a revised `dfs` might look -

```
def dfs(node, target: int, path: List[int]):
  if not node or target < 0:
    return
  elif isLeaf(node) and target - node.val == 0:
    yield [*path, node.val]
  else:
    yield from dfs(node.left, target - node.val, [*path, node.val])
    yield from dfs(node.right, target - node.val, [*path, node.val])
```

Near the end, you can see some computed values are duplicated -

```py
def dfs(node, target: int, path: List[int]):
  if not node or target < 0:
    return
  elif isLeaf(node) and target - node.val == 0:
    yield [*path, node.val]
  else:
    new_target = target - node.val  # <- compute once
    new_path = [*path, node.val]    # <- compute once
    yield from dfs(node.left, new_target, new_path)
    yield from dfs(node.right, new_target, new_path)
```

Now you can step through your tree using `for..in` -

```py
for path in dfs(my_tree):
  print(path)

# [...]
# [...]
# [...]
```

Or gather all of the paths in a `list` -

```py
print(list(dfs(my_tree))
# [ [...], [...], [...] ]
```